# I need help interpreting SATT estimate from logistic model on CEM matched data

Tags: r, logistic, matching

(sorry in advance for a stupid question, I have no experience with logistic regressions and no one to ask)

I'm trying to estimate the SATT point estimate from my matched data in R using a logit-model due to my dichotomous outcome variable. My treatment and control group is coded 1-0.

Using the output from coarsened exact matching, this is the results i'm getting:

Logistic model on CEM matched data:
SATT point estimate: 0.26004 (p.value = 0.368663)

I understand that it is not significant, but how do I interpret the effect?

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/

Comment: There is nothing special about the output of logistic regression as it relates to matching. Try searching the site for interpretation of logistic regression output, as there are many posts here about that.